# Porting GCC to Multiclet

Tags: c, gcc

I heard that GCC actually assumes registers, and requires CPU to have them to work.

What work should be done to remove this dependency, and port GCC to some register-less non-Von Neuman arch, like Multiclet?

Did somebody tried this? Is there some project and experience one can use if wants to work on this ?

If not, is there some other FOSS compiler that can be ported to something like Multiclet. LLVM has pretty much the same requirements like GCC, and it is unsuitable for me since I don't know C++. So it needs to be plain C. I hear that GCC is also adding C++ code now. But I can use some older version as starting point.

Comment: This might be a better question for a specialized GCC development list, like the [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/) mailing list.

Comment: They say GCC is written in C++ these days. That, and learning GCC internals is not necessarily an easier task than learning C++.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a combination of me not understanding the technology and English not being the author's first language, but the Multiclet website reminds me a lot of the Time Cube. That said, according to the website there isn't a need for a compiler because the processor runs a high level language directly. It also sounds like C++ probably wouldn't be a good fit for it.

Comment: I don't know anything about TimeCube, but MultiClet has C99 compiler available, but it is closed source. The "no low level language" means "no assembly language". C is regarded as high level language by them.

Answer (score 1):

Multiclet's C99 compiler is not closed source. Sources are available at their community suite. One may google it by name 'multiclet mcc lime'.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check them for some time and now I see they are now in the process dropping the old LCC and now moving to CC-BY licensed LiME project of Russan Academy of Science. But I can't clone the repository with git. And there is virtually no data on internet about LiME. I am fluent in Russian, so that is not a problem, but even Russian sites don't have any information.

Comment: Found something, very useful. In Russian http://multiclet.com/community/documents/8

Comment: @user333677 The work on this document is ongoing and it's quite outdated and incomplete. If you interested, you may find newer version of document here http://k.imm.uran.ru/lime/spec.pdf If you are interested to track development, you are welcome to subscripe here https://k.imm.uran.ru/mm/listinfo/l-devel. You may find CA-sertificate here http://k.imm.uran.ru/tls/k.ca.crt.

Comment: @bakhterev Спасибо большое, я буду следить за развитием ЛиМЕ компилятора. Очень интересная технология, так держат.